# Pretend You're Xyzzy Unable to Compile Class for JSP Error Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

New to Tomcat. Running 7 and https://github.com/ajanata/PretendYoureXyzzy.

Everything runs good with exporting the WAR and deploying it, but when I try to launch the app I get an error that it cannot compile class for JSP. The error is [here](http://pastebin.com/LXM7zn7A).

Eclipse has an error in the markers but I'm not sure if that's a problem. (Target runtime Apache Tomcat 7 is not defined.)

Comment: can u post your error the link which u given not showing anything.i have downloaded and ran your application it working fine.

Comment: It's too long to post as a comment, the pastebin isn't showing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The only error that matters is:

> Only a type can be imported. `net.socialgamer.cah.data.GameOptions` resolves to a package.

`GameOptions` is supposed to be a class or an enum.

Check the .jar file that contains `GameOptions`. It appears to be corrupt.

You may also need to check the `WEB-INF/classes/net/socialgamer/cah/data` folder of the .war file. It should *not* contain a folder called `GameOptions`, but may contain a file called `GameOptions.class`, if the classes were not packaged in a .jar file.

Comment: GameOptions.class is not there.